# Trouble Understanding a Problem

Tags: probability

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCK4q.jpg 
I don't understand how the normal random variable with parameters 0,1 equals (x-mu)/sigma=Z ~ N(0,1). 
If I plug that into the pdf of the normal distribution I get 1/sqrt(2pi) e^(-(x^2)/2).

Comment: The integral - or antiderivative - evaluates to $\sqrt{2\pi}$ NOT $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Hence, with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ factor you get the desired probability of $1$.

Comment: I understand how you get to the desired probability of 1. Maybe the question I asked was confusing. I'm asking why Z= (X - mu)/sigma

Comment: Because then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \cdot \exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma})\; dx = 0$; similarly, we get the desired value of $1$ for the integral involving a product of $(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2$ and the exponential.

Comment: As a footnote to this comment, I think this is the most pedagogically sound way to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral - or antiderivative - evaluates to $\sqrt{2\pi}$ NOT $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$. Hence, with the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ factor you get the desired probability of $1$.

Now, letting $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}$ and then we have $du = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{2}}$ and so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2/2)\; dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-u^2) \sqrt{2}\;  du = \sqrt{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-u^2)\;  du = \sqrt{2\pi}$, where this final integral is well known.

I appeal to a more rigorous method that is on Wikipedia, but a sketch would go as follows:

$$(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2)\; dx)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-(x^2+y^2))\; dx\; dy = \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} r\exp(-r^2)\; d\theta\; dr = 2\pi\cdot (-1/2)\cdot (-1) = \pi $$

So, $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2)\; dx = \sqrt{\pi}$ as desired.

**A FURTHER EXPLANATION:**

so why do we use $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$? The simplest reason is because then $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x-\mu}{\sigma} \cdot \exp(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma})\; dx = 0$; similarly, we get the desired value of $1$ for the integral involving a product of $(\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma})^2$ and the exponential. Like normalising, this guarantees what the integral will be through transformation.